# Door that opens if you have a lvl 1 keycard or higher

Tags: roblox

can somebody with this issue?

```
local door = script.Parent
local bool = false

local CanOpen1 = true
local CanClose1 = false

local AccessDenied = script.Parent.AccessDenied
local AccessGranted = script.Parent.AccessGranted



function openDoor()
    script.Parent.DoorOpen:play()
    for i = 3,(door.Size.z / 0.15) do
        wait()
        door.CFrame = door.CFrame - (door.CFrame.lookVector * 0.15)
    end
end

function closeDoor()
    script.Parent.DoorClose:play()
    for i = 3,(door.Size.z / 0.15) do
        wait()
        door.CFrame = door.CFrame + (door.CFrame.lookVector * 0.15)
    end
end

script.Parent.Parent.KeycardReader1.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(touch)
    if touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L1")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L2")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L3")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L4")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L5")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-Omni") and CanOpen1 == true then

        CanOpen1 = false
        AccessGranted:Play()
        wait(0.75)
        openDoor()
        wait(1)
        CanClose1 = true
    elseif touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L1")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L2")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L3")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L4")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L5")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-Omni" and CanClose1 == true then
        CanClose1 = false
        AccessGranted:Play()
        wait(0.75)
        closeDoor()
        wait(1)
        CanOpen1 = true
    elseif touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L1")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L2")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L3")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L4")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L5")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-Omni" and not bool then
        bool = true
        AccessDenied:Play()
        wait(2)
        bool = false
    end
end)

script.Parent.Parent.KeycardReader2.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(touch)
    if touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L1")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L2")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L3")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L4")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L5")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-Omni" and CanOpen1 == true then
        CanOpen1 = false
        AccessGranted:Play()
        wait(0.75)
        openDoor()
        wait(1)
        CanClose1 = true
    elseif touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L1")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L2")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L3")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L4")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L5")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-Omni" and CanClose1 == true then
        CanClose1 = false
        AccessGranted:Play()
        wait(0.75)
        closeDoor()
        wait(1)
        CanOpen1 = true
    elseif touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L1")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L2")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L3")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L4")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L5")or touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-Omni" and not bool then
        bool = true
        AccessDenied:Play()
        wait(2)
        bool = false
    end
end)
```

How can I make this work? Now it isn't opening at all, I don't know how to do it so if I get one of those cards in my inventory the door will open, it worked with one card but when I started putting card or card or card... then it stopped working, please can somebody help me quickly?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a close parenthesis in most of your last FindFirstChild calls in the if statements.

By the way, to avoid writing the same if..or clauses repeatedly, you could do the following:

```
local hasAnyCard = 
   touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L1") or
   touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L2") or 
   touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L3") or 
   touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L4") or 
   touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-L5") or    
   touch.Backpack:FindFirstChild("[SCP] Card-Omni")

if hasAnyCard and CanOpen1 then
 // [...]
elseif hasAnyCard and CanClose1 then
 // [...]
elseif // [...]
```

What will help you in programming is to always think about how you can avoid to repeat the same code.

Comment: It says " Workspace.KeycardDoor.KeycardDoor.ScriptedComponents.Door1.Script:11: attempt to index nil with 'Backpack' " and in the script you sent the "touch" has an orange line under it. How can I fix this?

Comment: The fix to your problem is adding the closing parenthesis after "Card-Omni" in your script (multiple times). The code I posted above was just a suggestion to make your script shorter and more readable, its not a replacement.